# PyCharm Python - Display __str__ of object instead of memory address in debugger

Tags: python, pycharm

As far as I remember, in IntelliJ, the debug window has the option to view the `toString()` of an object instead of its memory address. Is there a way to do this in PyCharm with an object's `__str__(self)`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be done with `__repr__`:

```
class Foo:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'foo object'

f = Foo()
pass # breakpoint here
```

This shows `'foo object'` in the debugger's variables window.

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm in variable view / debugging is showing `__str__` object representation instead of `__repr__`.

[Here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35529) was created a work-item on JetBrains website. Unforunetally I think there is still no progress.